# PrimeFaces: export chart as picture

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, charts

I'm trying to export my PF chart as picture following the showcase:

[enter link description here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/export.xhtml)

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:chart type="line" value="#{chartView.lineModel1}" 
             style="width:500px;height:300px" 
             widgetVar="chart"/>

    <p:commandButton type="button" 
                     value="Export" 
                     icon="ui-icon-extlink" 
                     onclick="exportChart()"/>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" 
              showEffect="fade" 
              modal="true" 
              header="Chart as an Image" 
              resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="output" 
                       layout="block" 
                       style="width:500px;height:300px"/>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function exportChart() {
        //export image
        $('#output').empty().append(PF('chart').exportAsImage());

        //show the dialog
        PF('dlg').show();
    }
</script>
```

But the popup window is blank:

[image]

I'm using **PF v5.1** but I've tried both the approaches:

for **PF v3.5** or older:

```
$('#output').empty().append(chart.exportAsImage()); dlg.show();
```

for **PF v4.0** or newer :

```
$('#output').empty().append(PF('chart').exportAsImage()); PF('dlg').show();
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where are you setting the graph as image to the dialog? You are just showing the dialog on button click? Ideally you should get the chart as image on button click and set the same to dialog and show the dialog then.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question. The export is part of javascript function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the **solution**:

```
function exportChart() {
  $('#form1\\:output').empty().append(chart.exportAsImage());
  dlg.show();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I also have like your requirement in my project. But, I fixed it by using `jquery`. It is working PF-4 or PF-5. 
Downlaod `jquery.js` and `html2canvas.js`. My jquery version is `jQuery v1.7.2`.

Here, my example exprot bar chart from primefaces showcase.

ChartView.java

```
@ManagedBean
public class ChartView implements Serializable {

    private BarChartModel barModel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        createBarModels();
    }

    public BarChartModel getBarModel() {
        return barModel;
    }

    private BarChartModel initBarModel() {
        BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel();

        ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();
        boys.setLabel("Boys");
        boys.set("2004", 120);
        boys.set("2005", 100);
        boys.set("2006", 44);
        boys.set("2007", 150);
        boys.set("2008", 25);

        ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();
        girls.setLabel("Girls");
        girls.set("2004", 52);
        girls.set("2005", 60);
        girls.set("2006", 110);
        girls.set("2007", 135);
        girls.set("2008", 120);

        model.addSeries(boys);
        model.addSeries(girls);

        return model;
    }

    private void createBarModels() {
        createBarModel();
    }

    private void createBarModel() {
        barModel = initBarModel();

        barModel.setTitle("Bar Chart");
        barModel.setLegendPosition("ne");

        Axis xAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
        xAxis.setLabel("Gender");

        Axis yAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
        yAxis.setLabel("Births");
        yAxis.setMin(0);
        yAxis.setMax(200);
    }
}
```

chartPrint.xhtml

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="imageFrom">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function saveAsImage() { 
                html2canvas($("#imageFrom\\:barChart"), {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                        theCanvas = canvas;
                        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                        $("#imageFrom\\:output").append(canvas);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <p:chart type="bar" id="barChart" model="#{chartView.barModel}" style="width:500px;height:300px;"/>     
        <p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Export" onclick="saveAsImage();PF('eventDialog').show();"/>
        <p:dialog id="eventDialog" widgetVar="eventDialog" resizable="false" width="520" height="300" appendToBody="true">
            <p:outputPanel id="output"/>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Output

[image]

**Don't forget** to use `appendToBody="true"` in dialog.

Answer (score 1):

PF('dlg').show() is the command that used to show dialog.
If you want  to show a chart inside dialog. Try this.

```
<p:chart type="line" 
         model="#{chartView.lineModel1}" 
         style="width:500px;height:300px" 
         widgetVar="chart"/>

<br />

<p:commandButton type="button" value="Export" 
                 icon="ui-icon-extlink" 
                 onclick="$('#output').empty().append(PF('chart').exportAsImage());PF('dlg').show();" 
                 />

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" 
          showEffect="fade" 
          modal="true" 
          header="Chart as an Image" 
          resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="output" 
                   layout="block" 
                   style="width:500px;height:300px"/>
</p:dialog>
```

or

```
<p:chart type="line" 
         model="#{chartView.lineModel1}" 
         style="width:500px;height:300px" 
         widgetVar="chart"/>

<br />

<p:commandButton type="button" value="Export" 
                 icon="ui-icon-extlink" 
                 onclick="PF('dlg').show();" 
                 />

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" 
          showEffect="fade" 
          modal="true" 
          header="Chart as an Image" 
          resizable="false">
    <p:chart type="line" 
         model="#{chartView.lineModel1}" 
         style="width:500px;height:300px" 
         widgetVar="chart2"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the first variant is the same as I used and it also displays just blank dialog. The second variant doesn't export chart as JPG (it just show the chart in popup dialog)...........